# What happened to Schrödinger'scat?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, users

I was always confident that [@Schrödinger'scat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703/) (user: 194703) would answer most of `TikZ` related questions. But today I realized that s/he has closed his/er account. What happened to Schrödinger'scat? Does anyone know about her/him?  I'm worried about her/him amid Covid19 and US protests.

Comment: Don't worry. Possible explanation: Probably the cat has accumulated enough good karma that they can be sure to be reincarnated as a marmot. Then there is nothing that kept them in their feline form.

Comment: I am relieved now. :) Do you know where was s/he from?

Comment: @C.F.G I think he escaped some box of an Austrian bloke.

Comment: I just want to know s\he (of course all users) is healthy?

Comment: @C.F.G He is healthy, don't worry :)

Comment: “What happened to @Schrödinger'scat?” The same that happened to @marmot (user121799).  Look here: https://topanswers.xyz/user?id=234&community=tex

Comment: I pray to God to give good health and long life to every one....

Comment: Quantum mechanically speaking his condition is described by a state function that say us that there is an equal probability that is dead or alive.

Comment: I also want to delete my profile. Good luck TSE users. (C.F.G)

Comment: Imho it's fine to have him/her outta here. What I don't get is why is s/he creating fake accounts from time to time. It's annoying.

Comment: Probably the most relevant answers I've read! I regret its absence